# Ubuntu 17.10 can't find Wireless Networks

Tags: wireless, internet, adapter

im new to Ubuntu. Installed version 17.10 yesterday and everything worked fine. Today I have problems with the Wifi adapter. 
Right after starting the PC it either won't find any Networks, or connects to the default but after a few minutes it looses connection and won't reconnect or find it.

At this point the GUI says: Wireless Networks are not available.

Ethernet works well.

I found this skript to diagnose the Adapter but i don't know for what i should look for. https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info

I let the skript post the output to: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25916283/

---

I also found this Article [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into/61547#61547)
 and looked the suggested things up.

**sudo lshw -class network**

```
sebastian@sebastian-NBLB2:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet
       Hersteller: Qualcomm Atheros
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:04:00.0
       Logischer Name: enp4s0
       Version: c0
       Seriennummer: 70:5a:b6:e5:0a:78
       Größe: 100Mbit/s
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       Ressourcen: irq:29 memory:d5000000-d503ffff ioport:3000(Größe=128)
  *-network DEAKTIVIERT
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: WiFi Link 5100
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:05:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlp5s0
       Version: 00
       Seriennummer: 00:22:fa:a3:e8:0e
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-16-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: irq:26 memory:d4000000-d4001fff
```

---

**lspci**

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
```

---

**dmesg**

```
[  386.861267] ---[ end trace 3adf6e467ef0813a ]---
[  399.440556] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
[  399.651807] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[  400.176106] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[  402.279606] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[  402.279622] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[  402.287097] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
[  402.452898] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[  402.975670] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[  405.084478] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[  405.084491] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[  405.091499] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
[  405.256725] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[  405.786548] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[  407.893306] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[  407.893324] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[  407.898971] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
[  450.520878] perf: interrupt took too long (4021 > 3952), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 49500
[  562.320819] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[  562.849135] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[  564.978213] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[  564.978231] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[  564.982438] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
[  575.674280] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[  576.203336] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[  578.320856] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[  578.320875] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
```

I would be glad if someone could take a look at it and show me where things go wrong.

THX,

Sebastian :)

Comment: **nmcli** shows me, that the WiFi is still connected and the Ethernet is unavailable) sebastian@sebastian-NBLB2:~$ nmcli
`wlp5s0: connected to Chen
 "Intel WiFi Link 5100 (AGN)"
 wifi (iwlwifi), 00:22:FA:A3:E8:0E, hw, mtu 1500
 ip4 default
 inet4 192.168.0.103/24

enp4s0: unavailable
 "Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet"
 ethernet (atl1c), AA:6B:73:43:A0:D8, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
 "lo"
 loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
 servers: 192.168.0.1
 interface: wlp5s0`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Wifi adapter gets disabled somehow, as is indicated by your lshw output.

> *-network DEAKTIVIERT

While I don't know the details of your system, it is very likely that is has something to do with the on/off functionality of your Wi-Fi adapter. Do you have a physical button for this? Most laptops do.
On my system there is a function button on the keyboard, which my Xubuntu ignores. The one way to disable/enable the adapter I know is via the network-manager (GUI). Click on the network symbol and make sure the **Enable Wi-Fi** option is checked. Maybe that helps, but of course it does not explain why your Wi-Fi automatically disables itself.

Comment: Yes, but isn't it weird, that the card is turned off and the Wifi in the Gui Network Settings Wifi is turned on?  And if turn it off/on it doesnt change the lshw output.

I also checked keyboard shortcuts (the Fn Keys, and manuel switch) but it doesn't change a thing. Neither in the lshw nor the GUI.

Comment: It is probably a bug in the firmware then. I can tell that you use the mainline kernel, which uses firmware=8.83.5.1. I happen to run the same driver as you (iwlwifi), but with much more recent firmware (17.459231.0). This is probably due to the fact, that I compile the kernel from source and it automatically pulls a more recent firmware. Unfortunately I don't know how to upgrade the firmware without compiling the kernel, but I'm sure it's easily possible. Might be worth a try, even though I don't have the same Wifi card as you, so it's not quite the same.

Comment: Ah, I just checked, it appears you are running the most recent firmware for your card ( see https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi), so there is nothing to upgrade I guess. Maybe you there is another program running, which interferes with the card? Maybe there are some BIOS settings that interfere with the WiFi somehow?

Comment: What is the output of  **sudo rfkill list all**?

Comment: This outputs for the Wireless LAN: Soft blocked :no & Hard blocked : no

Comment: I tried reinstalling Ubuntu today. But it doesn't solve the problem. After installation I updated the system and had connection for about half an hour. Than it disconnected again. My interfaces file shows two entries. "auto lo" and "iface lo inet loopback". Restarting network via systemctl does not work either.

Comment: I also recognized, that sometimes the Ethernet does also not work. This is the case right now. In the Network settings it tells me, that there is no cable plugged in.